# Heroku ignores system.properties file and does not change jdk version

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I'm trying to deploy jsp project on Heroku and I followed the guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner#create-a-procfile. When I tried to deploy, Heroku used jdk 1.8 (i need 17 in my project). So I created a `system.properties` file with the line `java.runtime.version=17`, commited and pushed it to master, but Heroku still tries to use jdk 1.8. What am I doing wrong?

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ruskaof</groupId>
    <artifactId>lab2WildFly</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>lab2WildFly</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>9.0.52.1</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Procfile:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

Comment: I've never used Heroku but in Tomcat you just simply specify the JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME in the startup script. Have in mind that you must have a JDK v 1.7 installed and you need to specify it's path somewhere so the 1.7 could be used. You can have multiple JDK versions on the same computer.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. System properties file should be at root level of the project.
   Refer: https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started
2. If that does not work for you you can instead use maven deployment

In your pom.xml
goto  section add following

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <configuration>
           <jdkVersion>17</jdkVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

if you do not want to use procfile as well you can add config for that as well in configuration section.

```xml
<configuration>
  ...
  <processTypes>
     <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main</web>
  </processTypes>
</configuration>
```

also you will see configuration for java opts there if required
Ref:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin

If you want to understand or customize and use any other java version
you can have a look at :
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version